# data at the root level is invalid. line 1 for SSIS

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, ssis, odata

I need to use VS2015 with SQL Server 2012 in my SSIS project.

When I changed Deployment Target Server Version from SQL Server 2016 to SQL Server 2012 I get following error.

OData V4.

[image: image here]

Stack Trace:

> Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1. (System.Xml)
>
> ---
>
> Program Location:
>
> at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
>         at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg)
>         at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseRootLevelWhitespace()
>         at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
>         at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
>         at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.OData.UI.ODataConnectionManagerForm.TestConnectionMiddle(Object callback)

Comment: I have this same problem, any luck?  I am trying to connect to powerBI OData.

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint https‍://localhost:44354/odata is not returning any XML.

You need to correct issues with that endpoint or switch to a different one.